# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return null value

Tags: c#, json

I did search but seem like i didnt find any solution for this... This is my sample Json:

```
{
  "WSettings":{
  "Message":"\"We are the universe's way of experiencing itself.\"<br/>- Kurzgesagt -",
  "universalMessageProcChance":10,
  "Hi":{
         "altName":"Hi",
         "normalState":"hi",
         "hState":"hi_h",
         "aState":"hi_a",
         "background":"bg_owo_r",
         "stateLayout":4,
         "backgroundLayout":1,
         "eventMessage":"Da"
     },
  "Yu":{
         "altName":"Al",
         "normalState":"al",
         "hState":"al_h",
         "aState":"ali_a",
         "background":"bg_owo_b",
         "stateLayout":4,
         "backgroundLayout":1,
         "eventMessage":"Da"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my classes:

```
public class WSettings
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int universalMessageProcChance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Hi")]
    public StateW Hi { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Yu")]
    public StateW Yu { get; set; }
}

public class StateW
{
    public string altName { get; set; }
    public string normalState { get; set; }
    public string hState { get; set; }
    public string aState { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
    public int stateLayout { get; set; }
    public int backgroundLayout { get; set; }
    public string eventMessage { get; set; }
}
```

and this to deserialize:

```
var w = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSettings>(File.ReadAllText(@"json.txt"));
```

It returns all attributes as null. I honestly dont know what is wrong there so please pardon my ignorant. Any help is appericated :)

Comment: `"WSettings"` is the property of an object. you need that object to deserialize it  `public class Rootobject { public Wsettings WSettings { get; set; }}` then `DeserializeObject<Rootobject>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another wrapper class on WSettings.
Try something like this:

```
public class WSettingsParent
{
    public WSettings WSettings { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like this:

```
WSettingsParent myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSettingsParent>(File.ReadAllText(@"json.txt")));
```

Here's a useful tool for checking that you can use to make sure the structure of your classes are properly set:
https://json2csharp.com/
Just paste your json on the left side and it will generate classes accordingly. (You might need some slight modifications but the big picture is visible there).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your JSON closely, `WSettings` is wrapped under one open-close curly brackets. It denotes that `WSetting` is also one property of top/Root level JObject.

Create new `Root` class and include `WSettings` as a property of it and deserialize your json with this Root class

**Additional class:**

```
public class Root
{
   //Property of existing WSettings class   
   public WSettings WSettings { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialization:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
....

var w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(File.ReadAllText(@"json.txt"));
                                   //^^^^^^ Use Root class instead of WSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

Already a good answer is provided. You can also try to use a JSON parser. its working

```
var jsparse = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"json.txt"));  
        var w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSettings>(jsparse["WSettings"].ToString());
```